# Comparing boolean numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, if-statement, numpy, boolean

I have two boolean numpy arrays of similar shape like:

```
a=[[True,True,False,False]]
b=[[True,False,True,False]]
```

How can I get an array `c` where 1 indicates that only array `a` is true,
2 indicates that only array `b` is true, 0 where both arrays are false and `nan` where both are true. So in this case the result should be [[nan,1,2,0]]].

Comment: What if both are True?

Comment: I've updated the question: if both are true an 'nan' should be returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`np.select`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
In [20]: a = np.array([True,True,False,False])

In [21]: b = np.array([True,False,True,False])

In [23]: np.select([a&~b, b&~a, a&b], [1, 2, np.nan], default=0)
Out[23]: array([ nan,   1.,   2.,   0.])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
np.where(a*b,np.nan,(2*b + a))
```

Sample run -

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: array([[ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [61]: b
Out[61]: array([[ True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [62]: np.where(a*b,np.nan,(2*b + a))
Out[62]: array([[ nan,   1.,   2.,   0.]])
```